# How to a package folder

Tags: packages

After install some individual packagefile.m, I can use `` <<packagefile` ``  to call it.

However, I just got a folder of package from
http://katlas.org/wiki/Setup#Setting_the_Path

According to instruction from, it should require no installation. And i don't know how to install the whole folder at once. And I used the same command `` <<KnotTheory` ``  (KnotTheory is the folder name), and it report

[image]

How to install the whole KnotTheory package folder or use it without installation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: One reads in the cited link "Start by downloading either the file KnotTheory.tar.gz or the file KnotTheory.zip (around 3MB each), and unpack either one. This will create a subdirectory KnotTheory/ in your current working directory. This done, no installation is required (though you may wish to check out Further Data Files and/or Setting the Path below). Start Mathematica and you're ready to go:".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the usual installation procedure: move the `KnotTheory` directory into `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications`.

You can open that location in your file manager using the Mathematica command `SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]`.

---

I quickly tried the package, and it does not appear to be fully compatible with Mathematica 12.1. There are some error messages on startup.  To correct these, open `init.m`, find the definition of `KnotTheoryDirectory`, and replace it with:

```
KnotTheoryDirectory[] = DirectoryName[$InputFileName]
```

This will solve the errors, but since the package was written a very long time ago, there is a chance that other problems may come up during use.

Comment: Thank you very much!